# How to use webapp2 on openshift?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud, webapp2, openshift

i have to install webapp2 on OpenShift Cloud.do OpenShift support webapp2.please tell me step by step procedure to use webapp2 on openshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with [this page](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html) on the web app site.

Comment: i go through that page,but i can't understand how to do the same on openshift